# Optimal solution of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In a problem set I found the following equation:

$$\alpha \ddot{x} = \lambda \theta^2 x$$

It says to find the "ideal trajectory" but I don't get what the problem refers as trajectory, I understand it as the angle $\theta$. Anyways, I don't know where to start solving it. I wanted to make $u=\ddot{x}$ but after that I don't know how to proceed. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: After looking up more problems I found a similar one but in another form and it asks for a solution. The better equation is this one:

$$\alpha \ddot{x} = \lambda \gamma^2 x$$

Comment: The derivative is taken w.r.to $\theta$ ?

Comment: There's a similar problem but with $\gamma$ instead of theta. Then it becomes $\alpha \ddot{x} = \lambda \gamma^2 x$, does it has more sense like that?

Comment: we need to know if $\gamma$ is a constant or the variable that's what I meant.

Comment: Yes, $ \gamma $ is taken as a constant

Comment: If you only have constants then it's a second order linear equation with constant coefficients.

Comment: Thanks. So can I state $u = \dot{x} \rightarrow \alpha \dot{u} = \lambda \gamma \int{u}$. But I don't know how to follow up.

Comment: If you only have constants then just solve it as usual with polynomial charactiristic $\alpha r^2-\lambda \gamma^2=0 $ .Find the values of r and then $x(t)=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}$